# jQuery add attr doesn''t work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a tooltip on my inputs however when I tried to add the attribute on textbox it doesn't work... maybe because jquery can't detect attribute added using jquery...

here's my code:

**JQUERY**

```
$('#CreateUser').on('click', function(){
$('.custom_required').each(function(){
    var labels = $(this).prev();
    var inputs = $(this);
    if(inputs.val() == "")
    {
        if(labels.hasClass('input_error') == false){
            labels.addClass('input_error');
            inputs.attr("data-toggle","tooltip");
            inputs.attr("title","Horay!");
            inputs.addClass('input_error');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        labels.removeClass('input_error');
        inputs.removeClass('input_error');
    }
});
});
```

**INITIALIZE PLUGIN**

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

when I add the `title` and `data-toggle` attribute directly on the inputs it worked fine... but when I tried to add the attribute using jquery doesn't work..

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you calling .tooltip() *after* adding the attributes? `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]')` selects all elements that *already* have the attribute at that moment, it doesn't know when other elements have the attribute added in the future.

Comment: @nnnnnn no sir...,, I just initialize the `tooltip`

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks sir... you are a great help.. =)